# python -m details in debugger

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand the steps that are involved when invoking the -m option. Using the debugger, I see that directly after my __init__.py is run, I'm taken to a set of pkgutil steps and then I get to run.py. From run.py, I get taken to an arbitrarily named .py file. Let's call it this_one.py. I don't see from where it gets to there. Can anyone point me to the documentation that explains using the -m option?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/ PEP 338 -- Executing modules as scripts

Comment: The doc about -m flag: http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Comment: ah. __main__.py. That's what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from comments to preserve the answer as an answer, *(Comments are not permanently displayed)*:

> [PEP 338](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) -- Executing modules as scripts – iMom0 1 hour ago
>
> The doc about -m flag:
>   [docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) – zhangyangyu 1 hour
>   ago
>
> *ah. main.py. That's what I was missing. Thanks. – numb3rs1x 1 hour ago*

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: As I said - I did __not__ originate the information above - it contains the answer to the question "Can anyone point me to the documentation that explains using the -m option?" and will preserve the information.